# ASP.net 4.6 c# Set text when page opens

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that allows the user to click the generate button to assign a random code to a text box. I want the text box to be assigned a default random code when the page opens. The text that is assigned needs to use the generate code method that the button is using. Where do I assign the text to the box when the page opens? I think it's the onload from the microsoft docs.

for example

```
// Override the OnLoad method to set _text to
// a default value if it is null.
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (_text == null)
        _text = "Here is some default text.";
}
```

but I Don't know where to put that.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="XMLAddUpdateDelete.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="xmlInsertUpdateDelete.XMLAddUpdateDelete" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Instructor</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    CourseID
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Description</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    AttendanceCode
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRandomCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate0" runat="server" OnClick="GenerateOTP" Text="Generate" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTechnology" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                        OnClick="btnAdd_Click" Width="150px" />
                    &nbsp; <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" 
                        onclick="btnClear_Click" Width="150px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>
                        XML Records</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdxml" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White"
                        BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" GridLines="Vertical"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdxml_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        onrowdeleting="grdxml_RowDeleting">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="na">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Designation")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CourseID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpEmailID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="na">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpTechnology" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Technology")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>


                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Azure" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="ActiveCaption" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="LightCyan" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="LightSalmon" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlInsertUpdateDelete
{
    public partial class XMLAddUpdateDelete : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
        }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Courses.xml"));

            if (ds != null && ds.HasChanges())
            {

                grdxml.DataSource = ds;

                grdxml.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {

                grdxml.DataBind();

            }
        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnAdd.Text.ToString().Equals("Update Record"))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Courses.xml"));

                int xmlRow = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(ViewState["gridrow"]));

                ds.Tables[0].Rows[xmlRow]["Name"] = txtName.Text;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[xmlRow]["Designation"] = txtDesignation.Text;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[xmlRow]["EmailID"] = txtEmailID.Text;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[xmlRow]["City"] = txtCity.Text;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[xmlRow]["Country"] = txtRandomCode.Text;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[xmlRow]["Technology"] = txtTechnology.Text;
                ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/Courses.xml"));
                BindGrid();

            }
            else
            {
                XmlDocument xmlEmloyeeDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlEmloyeeDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Courses.xml"));
                XmlElement ParentElement = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Course");
                XmlElement ID = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("ID");
                ID.InnerText = txtID.Text;
                XmlElement Name = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Name");
                Name.InnerText = txtName.Text;
                XmlElement Designation = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Designation");
                Designation.InnerText = txtDesignation.Text;
                XmlElement EmailID = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("EmailID");
                EmailID.InnerText = txtEmailID.Text;
                XmlElement City = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("City");
                City.InnerText = txtCity.Text;
                XmlElement Country = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Country");
                Country.InnerText = txtRandomCode.Text;
                XmlElement Technology = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Technology");

                Technology.InnerText = txtTechnology.Text;
                ParentElement.AppendChild(ID);
                ParentElement.AppendChild(Name);
                ParentElement.AppendChild(Designation);
                ParentElement.AppendChild(EmailID);
                ParentElement.AppendChild(City);
                ParentElement.AppendChild(Country);
                ParentElement.AppendChild(Technology);
                xmlEmloyeeDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(ParentElement);
                xmlEmloyeeDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Courses.xml"));
                BindGrid();
            }
            ClearControl();
        }

        private void ClearControl()
        {
            txtID.Text = string.Empty;
            txtName.Text = string.Empty;
            txtDesignation.Text = string.Empty;
            txtEmailID.Text = string.Empty;
            txtCity.Text = string.Empty;
            txtRandomCode.Text = string.Empty;
            txtTechnology.Text = string.Empty;
            txtID.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected void grdxml_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = grdxml.SelectedRow;
            txtID.Text = (row.FindControl("lblEmpId") as Label).Text;
            txtName.Text = (row.FindControl("lblEmpName") as Label).Text;
            txtDesignation.Text = (row.FindControl("lblEmpDesignation") as Label).Text;
            txtEmailID.Text = (row.FindControl("lblEmpEmailID") as Label).Text;
            txtCity.Text = (row.FindControl("lblEmpCity") as Label).Text;
            txtRandomCode.Text = (row.FindControl("lblEmpCountry") as Label).Text;
            txtTechnology.Text = (row.FindControl("lblEmpTechnology") as Label).Text;
            ViewState["gridrow"] = row.RowIndex.ToString();
            btnAdd.Text = "Update Record";
            txtID.Enabled = false;



        }

        protected void grdxml_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Courses.xml"));
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
            ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/Courses.xml"));
            BindGrid();
        }

        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearControl();

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GenerateOTP(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                //string alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                //string small_alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                string numbers = "1234567890";

                string characters = numbers;
                //if (rbType.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
                //{
                //characters += alphabets + small_alphabets + numbers;
                //characters += numbers;
                //}
                //int length = int.Parse(ddlLength.SelectedItem.Value);
                int length = 5;
                string otp = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    string character = string.Empty;
                    do
                    {
                        //int index = new Random().Next(0, characters.Length);
                        int index = new Random().Next(0, 5);
                        character = characters.ToCharArray()[index].ToString();
                    } while (otp.IndexOf(character) != -1);
                    otp += character;
                }
                //lblOTP.Text = otp;
                txtRandomCode.Text = otp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're working in Visual Studio, you can double-click on the button control on the design surface and it will open the code-behind page with a new generated handler for the button code. There you can put your logic, (i.e., txtRandomCode.Text = "what ever string"). Without ajax or any other contributing mutations, this will cause a page to reload when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the generation of the page is done server-side before it is displayed to the user regarding the ASP side of things (disregarding any AJAX that is triggered and posted to the page that may be called client-side) you can just provide these instructions in the `Page Load` method.

If you look at the [life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms178472(v=vs.85))

You can see that it would be acceptable for your purpose to initialise the control and set properties such as text in the `Page Load` method for when the page is created. All you need is for `runat="server"` to be implied and to access the control from the `code behind` using it's ID. You can then set its `innerHTML` to whatever you like or it's `.Text` property or `Value`.

The assignment will look something like this:

```
//Front-end:
<input id="txt" runat="Server" type="text" />

//Code behind:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt.Value = "Bob123";
}
```

Or this if it's an ASP control:

```
//In the .aspx:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>



//In the .aspx.cs:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = SomeMethod();
}

public string SomeMethod()
{
    return "Foo";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The text that is assigned needs to use the generate code method that the button is using. Do I put that front-end code in the aspx file and the code behind goes in what file?

Comment: @Blocks Front-end refers to `.aspx` code-behind refers to `aspx.cs`

Comment: I have the code for the generator in the .cs file. GenerateOTP. Do I need to put it in a method?
        protected void GenerateOTP(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: If by `.cs` you mean the `.cs` in this line of your code: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="XMLAddUpdateDelete.aspx.cs"` that is what is nominally referred to as the 'code behind'.

You don't have to so long as you set the Text/Value of the TextBox from within that method, you could create a new method for the purpose of initializing it for the first time, however. Just note that if you do it from within that method, every time that method is called it will fire that code.

Comment: Thanks the code behind is where the listing above starts with namespace xmlInsertUpdateDelete. It sounds like I need to create a new method to set a code for the first time the page loads.

Comment: That would be the ideal way of handling it, a separation of concerns is generally the smartest way to approach something like this.